# Как закодировать строку в little-endian на Erlang'е

Tags: erlang

Необходимо закодировать строку в little-endian в приложении на Erlang'е
для последующего включения в бинарное сообщение. Есть ограничение на длину
этого поля - 20 байт. Строка - fdQCuk_QY35F91.

```
1> C = "fdQCuk_QY35F91".
"fdQCuk_QY35F91"
2> X = term_to_binary(C).
<<131,107,0,14,102,100,81,67,117,107,95,81,89,51,53,70,57,
  49>>
3> L = unicode:characters_to_binary(X, {utf16, little}).
<<230,174,131,224,184,128,230,145,166,228,141,145,230,173,
  181,229,133,159,227,141,153,228,152,181,227,132,185>>
4> byte_size(L).
27
```

Получается в итоге 27 байт, что наводит на мысль, что
метод не верный. Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
1> C = "fdQCuk_QY35F91".
"fdQCuk_QY35F91"
2> L = unicode:characters_to_binary(C, {utf16, little}).
<<"fdQCuk_QY35F91">>
3> byte_size(L).
14
```